# Stepper Motor Voltage

Tags: arduino, transistors, stepper-motor, switching, arduino-uno

I am having a problem making a stepper motor run. The problem is that the voltages that I am reading from the motor never reach zero (they move from a high voltage to a smaller voltage) so they never are switching on and off (from a high voltage to 0) as I thought it would.

Right now I have the following setup:

[image: An Arduino pin connected to TIP122 base with a 17k resistor in between while its collector is connected to the motor's inductor and a flyback diode in parallel. The voltage source is connected to the collector and is 24V]
The pulse source is an Arduino Uno and the inductance and resistance I got from the motor's datasheet.

What I was hoping for was if somebody could tell me if the direction I am going to is the right one. Should it work like a switch? And if it should what are some possibilities of why it isn't working?

EDIT: I accidentally wrote 47 Ohms on the motors resistance, it was supposed to be 4.7 ohms.

Answer (score 1):

Darlington pairs have very high saturation voltage. 
In this case if you refer to the datasheet for the [TIP122](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF) you will see that you might expect anything from 2-4V across the C-E.

[image]

In your case the saturation voltage will be very high because you have minimal base current for the TIP122.

A FET may be a better device to consider.

**Update**: The base current you use is far too low. You have to overdrive the base to ensure the final transistor gets closer to saturation.

Using the Fairchild datasheet for the [TIP122](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf) (there is an error in the OnSemi version) you get this graph.

[image]

For Ib=Ic/250 you will need 4mA of base current (it's slightly more complicated than this because of the internal resistors). With a Vbe(sat) of around 1.5V you need an 875 Ohm base resistor driving from a 5V Arduino.

This should give you a Vce(sat) of approximately 0.8V at 1A.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that on the datasheet (I am still new to reading them). I noticed I drew the circuit wrong, the motor's resistance should be 4.7 ohms not 47 ohms. The Base current I calculated to be about 0.25 mA so that the Collector current can be 1 A, wouldn't that produce the Collector-Emitter Voltage to be  close to 3 V? Or am I analyzing it completely wrong?

Comment: @EstebanCaceres I added to the answer.

Comment: Ok,I will give it a try as soon as I can. I think I know my mistake, I used the DC current gain (which only applies when it is in active region, right?) instead of that relationship between which applies when it is in the saturation region.